# Why don't these python scripts do the same thing?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, list, matrix

I want to rotate matrix n x n by 90 degrees. My question is why these codes don't do the same thing?

First code (this code work as I want)

```
def rotate(matrix: List[List[int]]) -> None:
        result = [[0 for _ in range(len(matrix))] for _ in range(len(matrix))]
        for i in range(len(matrix)):
            for j in range(len(matrix)):
                result[i][j] = matrix[-j-1][i]

        for i in range(len(matrix)):
            for j in range(len(matrix)):
                matrix[i][j] = result[i][j]
```

Second code

```
def rotate(matrix: List[List[int]]) -> None:
        result = matrix.copy()
        for i in range(len(matrix)):
            for j in range(len(matrix)):
                matrix[i][j] = result[-j-1][i]
```

Could you explain me this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why the first code works as expected and the second one doesn't is due to how the copying of the matrix is performed.

In the first code, you are creating a completely new matrix called result and filling it with zeros. You then copy the rotated values from the original matrix to the new matrix. Finally, you copy the rotated values back into the original matrix. This process ensures that you don't modify the original matrix while doing the rotation, which is important for the correct result.

In the second code, you are using the copy() method to create a new matrix called result. However, copy() only creates a shallow copy of the list, which means that the inner lists are still referring to the same objects. When you modify the original matrix in the loop, you are also inadvertently modifying the result matrix because they share the same inner lists. This is why the second code doesn't produce the correct result.

To fix the second code, you can create a deep copy of the matrix using the copy module's deepcopy() function:

```py
from typing import List
from copy import deepcopy

def rotate(matrix: List[List[int]]) -> None:
    result = deepcopy(matrix)
    for i in range(len(matrix)):
        for j in range(len(matrix)):
            matrix[i][j] = result[-j-1][i]
```

This will create a completely new matrix that doesn't share any objects with the original matrix, allowing you to perform the rotation correctly.